# Code to determine the opening of an incomplete ellipse

Tags: c#, algorithm

I have an cut-off ellipse that I would like to render. The cutting off portion is done by the intersection with another ellipse (imagine the other ellipse blocking off the original ellipse).

Referring to the 2 ellipses below, where t1, t2 represents the parametric t1, t2 as i trace out the ellipse, giving points p1, p2.

[image]

How would I capture the portion that is empty using a data structure? My initial pseudocode goes something like this:

```
for(t = 0 to 360 degrees)
{
    if(point_t intersects with ellipse)
    {
        if(P1 is not set) set t corresponding to P1 as start_t;
        else set t corresponding to P2 as end_t
    }
}
```

then the "cut-off" region would be given by `start_t <= t <= end_t`.

However, this code will only work for the first diagram. In the 2nd diagram, since the "cut-off" region is not continuous for the range, as the actual cut-off region would be expressed as

`0 <= t <= P1 && P2 <= t <= 360 degrees`.

How should I write the algorithm to solve for all these cases? I will need a precise definition (such as the range of t values of the cut-off) of the cut-off part, as I will need to use this value to solve further line intersection problems with these cut-off ellipses.

Comment: Risking to look silly, may I suggest to check if the ellipse is continuous at t=0 or not? If not check where P1 actually starts and thn transform the starting point from 0 to P1 and the end to 360+P1.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but in this case, wouldn't the region be just the entire circle from p1 -> p1 + 360 degrees?

Comment: Yes. Wasn't that what the code intended for? I don't know the logic to detect two intersecting ellipses but your first line (for loop) tells me that you want to loop on a circle from 0 to 360.

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me the exact definition of the occlusion. And of course you haven't mentioned what API you're using for rendering. But all of the GUI APIs I'm aware of that are supported with C# include using some type of region/shape for clipping. Assuming this is strictly a _rendering_ problem, you should be able to just exclude the ellipse that is occluding the rendered one from the clip region during rendering, and achieve the effect you want. If you provide more specifics about the environment, a genuine, detailed answer could be given.

Comment: @user3021830 Yes the loop from 0->360 degrees is to check over the entire region of the ellipse to see which are the empty/non-empty points of the ellipse. I may be understanding your reply incorrectly, but what you suggested would mean that the output of the function would give `start_t <= t <= end_t`, where `start_t = p1` and `end_t = p1+360 degrees`?

Comment: @PeterDuniho Mine is not a rendering problem only, as I need to have a description of the cut-off geometry (in terms of a range of t values), in order to do further processing. My exact problem is to solve for intersection of lines within this cut-off geometry, so I will need to have a mathematical description for the cut-off portion.

Comment: @JohnTan, definetely that was what I meant.

Comment: Then I would represent the missing portion in angles, not points. Mathematically determine the intersection of the two ellipses; if the intersection is two points (if fewer then they don't intersect in an occluding way), then determine the angle for each intersection. Arbitrarily decide whether you will specify the missing arc clockwise or counter-clockwise. If the missing arc crosses the 0 degree point, that's fine...you just start with a negative angle (or end, depending on the direction you chose for your representation).

Comment: @user3021830 In this case, then let's say for the 2nd ellipse, the cut-off region should be `0 <= t <= P1 && P2 <= t <= 360 degrees`, instead of `p1 _t <= t <= p1+360 degrees`

Comment: @PeterDuniho Unfortunately, I am unable to solve for the intersection mathematically (via simultaneous equation), as the equation would be quartic. The only way I can think of is to discretize each point on the ellipse and test point by point (hence the `for` loop from `0->360`)

Comment: @JohnTan, for simplicity and easiness I would always go for shifting the circle to start from the intersection point. I think t = p1 => p1+360 should work for both ellipses.

Comment: My understanding is that while an exact solution would be infeasible, it should be possible to write reasonable code that would solve the equation numerically. Here are some links that seem useful: http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/66877.html, http://maptools.home.comcast.net/~maptools/BivariateQuadratics.pdf, http://math.stackexchange.com/a/864186, http://www.analyzemath.com/EllipseProblems/ellipse_intersection.html

Answer (score 2):

Your image implies axis aligned ellipses if that is not true specify it in OP

1. intersection of 2 ellipses can create

   - 0 cut off if fully inside/outside
   - 1 cut off if intersecting on single side
   - 2 cut offs if intersecting on 2 sides
   - full cut off is both ellipses are identical
   - [image: examples]
2. intersection point

   - you need to obtain all the intersection points
   - so either solve it algebraically/numerically
   - `x0+a0*cos(t0)=x1*a1*cos(t1)`
   - `y0+b0*sin(t0)=y1*b1*sin(t1)`
   - where: `x0,y0` is center, `a0,b0` are semiaxises and `t0` is parameter of the first ellipse
   - where: `x1,y1` is center, `a1,b1` are semiaxises and `t1` is parameter of the second ellipse
   - or convert the problem to intersection of lines
   - [image: lines intersection]
   - by sweeping booth ellipses by constant angle
   - transforming each ellipse to convex polygon
   - the more points the more precise intersection you get
   - if the lines lay in each other then choose the middle point of their common part
3. what info to store?

   - you need parameter pairs of the gaps or the rest in the start-end form
   - so for each intersection point you need to decide if it is start of gap or end
   - so you should have a list of intersection parameters up to 4 points/angles (sorted by angles)
4. you can ignore 0,1 points cases
5. 2 points is the simplest case

   - so you have intersection angles `ang0,ang1` where `ang0<ang1`
   - so just check if point `ang0+0.01*(ang0+ang1)` is inside the second ellipse
   - if yes then `ang0` is start of gap and `ang1` is end
   - so render:
   - `for(t=0   ;t<=ang0  ;t+=step)...`
   - `for(t=ang1;t<=360deg;t+=step)...`
   - if not then it is the other way around
   - `for(t=ang0;t<=ang1  ;t+=step)...`
6. 3 points case is rare

   - this happen when ellipse is cutting one side and only touching the other
   - so find which intersecting angle is outside the intersection on each side and ignore it
   - so compute `dang=0.01*min(|ang1-ang0|,|ang2-ang0|,|ang2-ang1|)`
   - and find the touching point where `ang? +/- dang` is outside intersecting point
   - then ignore it and handle the rest as 2 point case
7. 4 points case

   - so compute `dang=0.01*min(|ang1-ang0|,|ang2-ang0|,|ang3-ang0|,...)`
   - now find if `ang0` is start of gap `ang0-ang1`
   - if yes render
   - `for(t=0   ;t<=ang0  ;t+=step)...`
   - `for(t=ang1;t<=ang2  ;t+=step)...`
   - `for(t=ang3;t<=360deg;t+=step)...`
   - if not then
   - `for(t=ang0;t<=ang1  ;t+=step)...`
   - `for(t=ang2;t<=ang3  ;t+=step)...`
8. identicall ellipses

   - if both ellipses have the same center, semiaxes and rotation
   - then cut off whole ellipse (render nothing)
9. unification

   - you can convert whole this to store non gaps chunks of ellipse
   - as set of angle pairs
   - `(start,end)` angle from each render for ...

[notes]

- `dang` can be any small enough angle step (must be smaller then smallest gap) but if it is **too small** then your intersection computation can **give false positives**
- the polygon conversion works even for non axis aligned ellipses
- if you use sweeping then you already have information if intersection point is start or end of gap so you can ignore dang if know how to use it
- beware the radians/degrees for goniometric functions ...
- if you want to solve intersections algebraically and want to avoid transcendent functions then use implicit ellipse equations instead
- while rendering you should handle the end angle crossing for example

  ```
  for (t=ang0;t<=ang1;t+=step)
   {
   if (t>=ang1) { t=ang1; e=1; } else e=0;
   ...
   if (e) break
   }
  ```
- How to determine if point `x,y` is inside axis aligned ellipse `x0,y0,a,b` ?
- first convert `(x0,y0)` to `(0,0)` by translating coordinate system
- so problem changes to: is point `(x-x0,y-y0)` inside `0,0,a,b` ?
- and that is easy:
- `ang=atan2(y-y0,x-x0);`
- `if ((x-x0<=a*cos(ang))&&(y-y0<=a*sin(ang))) is_inside else is_outside;`
- if you have non axis aligned ellipse then add rotation to match axis angles ...

Answer (score 0):

As it is possible for two ellipses to intersect up to 4 times (and thus resulting in two cut-off regions anyways), i would suggest you run the code like you suggested, but store all resulting intervals in a list.

Meaning:

The first value for which `if(point_t intersects with ellipse)` is `true` is stored as startvalue for the first interval. You continue until `if(point_t intersects with ellipse)` is false and set it as end parameter. Then repeat.

The result is a list of start/endvalues over which you can iterate for further calculations. Also if you need the lenght of each interval, you can modify the list afterwards if an intervall starts with 0 to store for example `{340,20}` as intersection-intervall.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you only need to describe a single cut-off interval, I would recommend a (Begin, Extent) representation rather than (Begin, End). The Extent parameter is a value in range 0° to 360°, which is not sensitive to the jump of the angle. You can even assign it a sign to allow distinguish between clockwise and counterclockwise traversals.

A similar trick is possible if you want to describe a sequence of arcs: you may either provide the (Begin, Extent) information for every arc, or (Begin, Extent, Extent, Extent...) bounds for alternating included/excluded arcs.

Comment: If your question is actually how to clip an ellipse with another, please rephrase it.